# Please identify the Red Dwarf character that dies writing his name on Earth

Tags: character-identification, red-dwarf

Although I've owned several copies of "Infinity Welcomes Careful Drivers", I continue to *loan* them and never get them back. IIRC, there was a garbageman hovering above Earth(now the landfill for the galaxy), writing his name in excrement when he falls to his doom. This happened right before Earth went rogue.

I looked on the internet after a futile search for the book and came up empty.

I'm hoping that once I get his name I can track down a picture or sketch of his vehicle which I hope to build out of Lego.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The monumental graffiti artist's name was John Ewe.

> **John Ewe** shut down the satellite link, and followed his hairy beer-belly back to the front of the ship. Before he could reach the
> safety webbing, a massive pocket of methane turbulence rocked the
> refuse craft and sent him staggering into the first-aid box. He
> fingered the gash that grinned bloodily on his brow and invented two
> new swear words. The methane storms had been getting worse over the
> past few years, and he knew he should have consulted the
> meteorological computer before he ventured from his safety harness. As
> he lurched to his feet, a second methane blast hit the ship under its
> belly, sending him stumbling back down the narrow aisle. As he
> slithered helplessly backwards, his flailing arm caught the
> door-release mechanism, and the cockpit's emergency exit swung open.
>
> His fat fingers scrambled for a hand-hold, but found nothing until he
> slid through the open doorway, and he grabbed the rim of the
> footledge. For thirty seconds he dangled, screaming, over Europe.
>
> Then he dangled no more.
>
> He plunged from the yawing garbage ship, and drowned in his own
> signature.
>
> 'Ewe woz 'ere', it said. And it was right, 'e woz.

For the record, the book he appears in is [*Red Dwarf: Better Than Life*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Than_Life), not [*Red Dwarf: Infinity Welcomes Careful Drivers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf:_Infinity_Welcomes_Careful_Drivers)

Comment: Too funny. When I looked up John Ewe Red Dwarf on the web, my question was the 4th or 5th item on the hit list. My quest continues.

Comment: After spotting a question in the "Hot Meta Posts" section, I decided for the laugh to ask this question to ChatGPT ("What Red Dwarf character dies while spelling his name in giant graffiti on Earth") - the answer given was Arnold Rimmer, in "Me^2" ...  If I mention that the letters were made of rubbish it says Dave Lister in "Only the Good"

Comment: @komodosp - All the more reason for the powers-that-be at Stack Exchange to give CHATGPT access to our database...