# Red Dwarf, backwards: why is writing reversed?

Tags: red-dwarf

In the Red Dwarf episode Backwards, the crew travels in time to a time after the end of the universe. It is established that universal expansion has reversed, and time with it. So they are on earth in the modern day, but everything takes place reversed in time.

However, writing is spelled backwards. If they're in the present, but time is reversed, why is the writing now backwards?

Edit: While some people feel the answer to this may be identical to an unrelated question about an unrelated episode. The question is not the same question.

Comment: Poorly thought out writing, or, more likely, [Rule of Funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny). -- Warning!  That's a TVTropes link; follow it and you could lose hours of what could otherwise be productive time..

Comment: @K-H-W I don't think it is poorly thought out writing at all. It was fully the second answer you give, which, is probably the best answer for this question. you should submit it.

Comment: Honestly, there is **so much** *why* in that episode, I think the only possible answer is "because funny."

Comment: I think I've finally found a red dwarf question where nobody will answer "because he's a smeg head".

Comment: How much say did Grant and Naylor have in the creation of the TV series?

Comment: My answer to the dupe question above addresses this. As K-H-W says in his comment, funny is king.

Comment: I'm having reservations about closing every Red Dwarf question as a duplicate just because the answer is *probably* going to be "because it was funny".

Comment: I'd ask why Cat gets such an odd look on his face and walks funny at the end, but I won't.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - That is true, however some questions will have any answer (e.g. [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99135/please-identify-the-red-dwarf-character-that-dies-writing-his-name-on-earth?rq=1)) and some clearly will not

Comment: @RedactedStack - This is explained in the accompanying novel. In vivid detail. And yes, it's exactly what you think it is.

Comment: @Richard Rhetorical. And ew...

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much every plot inconsistency in Red Dwarf can be attributed to the trope "[Rule of Funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)", e.g. where the **comedy value** of a scene takes immediate priority over any consideration of continuity or common sense.

[This interview](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/features/interviews/doug-naylor-anniversary/) with Douglas Naylor illustrates this point quite nicely:

> **Do you think of Red Dwarf as a science-fiction show with comedy in, or a sitcom with science fiction in?**
>
> *I think... well, actually, you could argue, it's been both! Whether we intended that is something else...*
>
> ***It was always intended to be a comedy first. They were really so linked, but we had to pretend it wasn't science fiction when we sold it, because everyone said that science fiction didn't sell... and yet the science fiction part, from our point of view, was actually our pitch!*** *Because otherwise, it was just about two guys in a spaceship. And especially with nobody else there, what was it going to be about? Just arguments about chicken soup dispensers, and skutters. So it was the science fiction tropes that gave it the impetus and the energy, and the originality. And also, the ability to go anywhere, get off the ship, whatever.*
>
> *But I think if it's a science fiction show with comedy, that's probably when we've done it wrong. It should be the other way around*

And

> **Did you find it was more important to tell the best story possible at the time, rather than being concerned about whether it lined up with past backstory?**
>
> *Absolutely, yeah. And in the end, the laugh is king - and Rob's feeling was certainly that **if it works, it works, and don't worry about it.***

Comment: If I may play devils advocate for a minute. Is it funny that the writing is reversed, or is it a way of (erroneously) re-introducing the "backwards" concept? I don't really see it as the root of any comic dialogue.

Comment: @AJFaraday - The humour in that situation comes from Lister and the Cat not realising that NODNOL is London backwards. It highlights their stupidity

Comment: @AJFaraday Agreed, also allows for the Rule of Funny to be exhibited in Listy's fight scene and the cabaret act of the amazing rever brothers